# how to install tkinter with Pycharm?

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

I used `sudo apt-get install python3.6-tk` and it works fine. Tkinter works if I open python in terminal, but I cannot get it installed on my Pycharm project. `pip install` command says it cannot find Tkinter. I cannot find python-tk in the list of possible installs either.

Is there a way to get Tkinter just standard into every virtualenv when I make a new project in Pycharm?

Edit: on Linux Mint

Edit2: It is a clear problem of Pycharm not getting tkinter guys. If I run my local python file from terminal it works fine. Just that for some reason Pycharm cannot find anything tkinter related.

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205820229-GUI-Using-Tkinter

Comment: I cannot import either tkinter or Tkinter

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: added it in, Linux Mint.

Comment: From the link: *To continue the Ubuntu example, you would need to install either the `python-tkinter` package or `python3-tkinter`, depending again on python 2.x (default) or python 3.x.* `sudo apt-get install python3-tkinter`

Comment: Like I said, I installed it, it works fine outside Pycharm, just not in Pycharm. I am using python 3.7 and neither tkinter or Tkinter works.

Comment: Link from Elliot Frisch solves this problem.

Comment: It does not for me, none of the solutions here solve the problem in Pycharm on Linux Mint. I ended up using just VScode. A whole bunch of modules are bugged out for me on Pycharm.

Maybe it works for the paid version, who knows.

Answer (score 7):

For `python 2` use:

```
sudo apt-get install python-tk
```

For `python 3` use:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

When you display info about packages it states:

> Tkinter - Writing Tk applications with Python2 (*or Python 3.x*)

---

But my assumption is that PyCharm created it's own virtualenv for you project, so you are probably using wrong python interpreter in PyCharm.

Open your PyCharm project. Go to `File->Settings->Project->Project Interpreter`. At top, you will see what python  interpreter is PyCharm using for a current project. If that's not the system one you have, find path to system interpreter and add it to `Python Interpreters` in PyCharm.

More details on [PyCharm Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html).

Comment: Hi @TheProgramMAN123 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you use the right import statement for your version of Python.

Python 2.7

```
from Tkinter import *
```

For Python 3.x

```
from tkinter import *
```

Answer (score 0):

Pycharm is having problems with tkinter probably because you're using the flatpak version. I had the same problem with Pycharm as well as VSCode. It wouldn't recognize module tkinter. I tried using the snap version of Pycharm and now it is working perfectly fine. I think you should give it a try before looking for tkinter.

```
sudo snap install pycharm-community --classic
```

Answer (score -1):

Python already has tkinter installed. It is a base module, like random or time, therefore you don't need to install it.

Comment: Then why do I get the error ModuleNotFoundErr: No modlue named 'Tkinter' when I try to use matplotlib

Comment: @sam, tkinter is not pre-installed on linux, at least not on all distros

Answer (score -1):

Pycharm comes with tkinter by default. But there are some circumstances that your installation might be missing tkinter. In that case you have to follow below mentioned steps.

For python 2 use:

```
sudo apt-get install python-tk
```

For python 3 use:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

When you display info about packages it states:

Basically you have to import it

```
from tkinter import *

top = Tk()
# Code to add widgets will go here...
top.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1):

To install tkinter in Pycharm, install the module “future” and restart pycharm. Tkinter will be imported, to access it use:

```
from future.moves import tkinter
```

If it don't work for you, search where tkinter lies in "future" package using cmd:

```
$ find . -name "*tkinter*"
```

and import accordingly.

Comment: you can check my solution from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53797598/how-to-install-tkinter-with-pycharm/68347377#68347377

Answer (score -2):

For Python 3.8:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.8-tk
```